# iOS crash in CoreLocation

Tags: ios, crash, core-location

I'm seeing this crash my iOS app after it's been running for 10 minutes:

```
Date/Time:       2012-02-22 15:26:41.415 -0800
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x49980286
Crashed Thread:  6
```

The offending thread:

```
Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x33ed32f8 std::string::compare(std::string const&) const + 8
1   CoreLocation                    0x3095ad54 std::_Rb_tree<std::string, std::pair<std::string const, void ( block_pointer)(CLConnectionMessage*)>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<std::string const, void ( block_pointer)(CLConnectionMessage*)> >, std::less<std::string>, std::allocator<std::pair<std::string const, void ( block_pointer)(CLConnectionMessage*)> > >::find(std::string const&) + 32
2   CoreLocation                    0x30959964 CLConnection::handleMessage(CLConnectionMessage*) + 16
3   CoreLocation                    0x3095a78c __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 360
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x37a428c2 __XPC_CONNECTION_EVENT_HANDLER_CALLOUT__ +    30
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x37a3bd5c _xpc_connection_recv_message + 500
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x37a3bb18 _xpc_connection_wakeup_recv + 160
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x37a3b9b8 _xpc_connection_wakeup2 + 1264
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x37a3b3f6 _xpc_connection_wakeup + 62
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x36d7821e _dispatch_source_invoke + 510
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 40
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75caa _dispatch_queue_drain + 202
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 30
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75caa _dispatch_queue_drain + 202
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 30
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75caa _dispatch_queue_drain + 202
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d75b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up + 30
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x36d7676c _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 208
18  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ee21c8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x32ee209c start_wqthread + 0
```

The console doesn't give me any messages except to say that I have a crash. Any thoughts?

Comment: Show the CoreLocation code you are using.

Comment: It's a mature app ... there are literally thousands of lines of using CoreLocation.

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, you are trying to access overreleased object. Did you run your application in Zombies instruments ? and/or did you set NSZombie enabled environment variable that gives a bit more info about where its causing this problem ?

Comment: If its a mature app, can you show us the recent changes you made that may have lead to this crash?

Comment: I did catch this crash in Instruments running Zombies. When it crashed, I got the same crash log but Instruments didn't find an access to a deallocated object.

Comment: @Jim, I can't point to a specific change, seems it's been in the codebase for a while so it will be difficult to pinpoint. (also, thanks to the individual who down voted this question without telling me why they didn't like it ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after lots of digging I was able to repro the issue and find what was causing it. This seems to occur if you call -[CLLocationManager startUpdatingLocation] and -[CLLocationManager stopUpdatingLocation] in a tight loop.

Comment: I too am seeing this same behavior of a crash occurring while the app is backgrounded and receiving location updates. However, I am not invoking `startUpdatingLocation` and `stopUpdatingLocation` in any sort of loop.

Comment: What do you mean by tight loop? 
I am getting a crash for CoreLocation as following: CoreLocation: CLConnection::sendMessageInternal . But I can't find any solution for it online.

Comment: I have set locationManager.delegate = nil when stopUpdatingLocation. 
locationManager.delegate = self when startUpdatingLocation. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I was having this trouble as well, but only on iOS 5.x (testing in Simulator, don't have the device.) It seemed to occur when I had more than one location manager instance, and both had the delegate set.